# remove multiple occurrences of integers from list

Tags: python, list

So I have a problem where I need to remove the integers that occur more than n times from the list. This is giving me an error that remove(x) doesn't exist in the list. Help!

```
def answer1(data, n):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        item = 0
        if data.count(i) > n:
            item = i
            for k in range(len(data)):
                data.remove(item)
    print(data)

data = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
answer1(data, 2)
```

Comment: is the order important?

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work properly because you're [removing items from your list while iterating on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating). This shortens the list, but the loop iterating on it isn't aware of that (because of its internal index counter)

I would use `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences (good performance, as opposed to `count` which scans the list at each iteration) then filter the list using a list comprehension (as a bonus, the original input isn't modified)

```
import collections
def answer1(data, n):
   c = collections.Counter(data)
   return [x for x in data if c[x]<n]

data = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
a = answer1(data, 2)
print(a)
```

result:

```
[4, 5]
```

(and the initial order is preserved)